# Usage of 'yes and no'

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

A: Jennifer, Lauren and Mike don't have a car
B: **Yes and no**, Jennifer and Lauren don't have a car, but Mike has a car.

Is 'Yes and no' used correctly?

Comment: Well ... in speech, almost everything is correct - if used correctly! "Yes and no" there is fine, and so would be "Bullshit"!

Comment: I have only ever heard “yes and no” when responding to a question that presupposes a yes/no answer but requires a nuanced response. It seems out of place as a statement that is not a response.

Comment: If the implied question is whether they each have their own car, it should be _don't have cars_. Otherwise, it implies that they share a car between them.